# I need alarm to start after specified time interval but alarm is executing at the start and repeats after certain interval

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, repeat, repeatingalarm

> I have attached my code here for reference.
> I need alarm to be executed after certain interval but its starting at the beginning and repeating. Can i get a solution for this.
>
> AlarmManagerExample.java

```
   package com.example.alarmmanagerexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmManagerExample extends Activity {
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_manager_example);
        
        
        try {
            
            //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RingAlarm.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am =
                (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,     SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                    2*60*60,pendingIntent);
            
          } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

> activity_alarm_manager_example.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AlarmManagerExample" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> RingAlarm.java

```
package com.example.alarmmanagerexample;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.RingtoneManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    public class RingAlarm extends Activity {
            
           MediaPlayer mp=null ;
          
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                        
                        setContentView(R.layout.alarm);
                        Button stopAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm);
                        
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.audio);
                        
                        
                        stopAlarm.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                            
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                mp.stop();
                                finish();
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                 
                        playSound(this, getAlarmUri());
                    }
                 
                    private void playSound(final Context context, Uri alert) {
                         
                        
                        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    
                                   mp.start();
                                   
                                } catch (Throwable t) {
                                    Log.i("Animation", "Thread  exception "+t);
                                }   
                            }
                     });
                     background.start();
                   }
                 
                    @Override
                    protected void onDestroy() {
                        super.onDestroy();
                        mp.stop();
                    }               //Get an alarm sound. Try for an alarm. If none set, try notification,
                        //Otherwise, ringtone.
                    private Uri getAlarmUri() {
                        
                        Uri alert = RingtoneManager
                                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                        if (alert == null) {
                            alert = RingtoneManager
                                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                            if (alert == null) {
                                alert = RingtoneManager
                                        .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                            }
                        }
                        return alert;
                    }
                
    }
```

> Alarm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:text="Stop Alarm" android:id="@+id/stopAlarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alarmmanagerexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.alarmmanagerexample.AlarmManagerExample"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RingAlarm"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You need repeating alarm and it is repeating, then what is problem?

Comment: I need alarm to start after certain time interval like in the program i set it to repeat after every 7.2 seconds. But the alarm beats at the start of the program and gets repeated. Can i stop the alarm at the start.